# Rails - how to fetch from ActiveRecord object only specific records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, activerecord, hash

I get this from an ActiveRecord call:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [
  #<CarService id: nil, car_id: nil, car_service: 1, 
               created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, car_type: 0>, 
  #<CarService id: nil, car_id: nil, car_service: 11,
               created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, car_type: 1>]>
```

Once I get this, I need to filter only records where `car_type = "0"`. How to do that without doing another database call (`WHERE car_type = "0"`)?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

this:

```
car.car_services.select{|key, hash| hash['car_type'] == "1" }
```

does not work.

Comment: `car.car_services.select{ |car_service| car_service.car_type.to_s == "1" }`. BTW, this is _wrong_ approach. Another filtering query against DB would be faster and more reliable.

Comment: Did you try : `car.car_services.select{|car_service| car_service.car_type == 1 }` ?

Comment: why not `where`? if the result is big, `select` will take you a long time. it won't make another call if the query is altogether

Comment: can you show your original ActiveRecord call? ActiveRecord and ActiveRelation allow for chaining calls to refine your sql. This won't result in multiple sql executions. If we know what you called originally we might be able to attach a where that limits the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

just convert your result to an array then filter it like this

```
result = car.car_services.to_a.select do |e|
     e.car_type == "0"
end
```

Comment: calling select on ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy will actually convert the collection to an array. http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-select

Answer (score 0):

You can use scope in CarService model:

```
scope :type_ones, -> { where(car_type: 1) }
```

and you can use it like this:

```
car.car_services.type_ones
```

If you use enum, it will be better. Because the enum creates to scopes automatically instead of you. And of course it has more features. More about the [enum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).